# Topological Data Analysis

Tags: reference-request, topological-data-analysis

Beyond the basic math symbols you can type holding down shift on your keyboard, I don't know math symbols, or even how to meaningfully search for them.

I came across Topological Data Analysis https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.08227 and wanted to read it, but can't figure what to search for in things like image 5 of part 2 since I can't post an image.

What would I use to learn to read that on my own?

Comment: What question are you asking? It doesn't seem to have anything to do with topological data analysis, and (perhaps for this reason?) I find your second paragraph in particular confusing.

Comment: What is your mathematical background? For example, if you're unfamiliar with sets and random variables, then you would need to do a substantial amount of reading before you can read the paper you linked.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/813766/118539 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2065562/118539.

Answer (score 0):

You could try searching for introductory blog articles or videos to give you some idea of what topological data analysis is about. For instance, Matthew Wright's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2PSqWBIrn90) on Persistent Homology could be helpful, as could David Austin's [article](http://www.ams.org/publicoutreach/feature-column/fc-2016-12) *Finding Holes in the Data*.

However, if your mathematics background is that of a complete beginner then you will need to study a good part of university level mathematics (and refresh background school mathematics as needed). That is a question in its own right.